# Generate accessToken using oauth 2 for microsoft dynamics 365 crm in an angular app

Tags: angular, rest, oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm

I have an angular web app that I want to use to generate an access token & refresh token for MS dynamics 365 CRM for offline use. I am able to do it in the postman.

Usually, there are libraries to simplify the process. Is there any I can use with my angular app to generate it and store it in the backend?

Comment: which oauth2 grant are you using?

Comment: user_impersation for dynamic crm

Comment: I mean which oauth2 grant? like authorization_code or password or implicit or client_credentials? How are you doing it in postman? Do you have node as backend?

Comment: authorization_code

Comment: authorization_code . no just postman and nothing else in the backend.

Comment: for authorization_code you need backend service too to maintain the session and token. You can use this http://www.passportjs.org/

Comment: I will give it a try @ShwetaValunj Thanks!